# Woocommerce / Polylang Causes Add to Basket button to be disabled

Tags: wordpress, polylang

i've been experiencing this error so far: 
the Add to Basket button is disabled for variable products on the English version of my wordpress website, when instead everything works on the Italian version. Altho a couple of errors from the debug I found out that the mistake is related to the below code got from Google Chrome which i have no clue how to fix or avoid..any help or hints would be really appreciated..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at e.isMatch (add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1)
    at e.findMatchingVariations (add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.e.onUpdateAttributes (add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
e.isMatch @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
e.findMatchingVariations @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
(anonymous) @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
e.onUpdateAttributes @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
trigger @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
a.event.trigger @ jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
trigger @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
e.onFindVariation @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
trigger @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
a.event.trigger @ jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
trigger @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
e.onChange @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.12:1
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at VariationForm.isMatch (add-to-cart-variation.js:453)
    at VariationForm.findMatchingVariations (add-to-cart-variation.js:436)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (add-to-cart-variation.js:325)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.VariationForm.onUpdateAttributes (add-to-cart-variation.js:297)at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)at Object.trigger (jquery.js:3)at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:633)

Comment: Apparently this is what is causing the errors/**
  * See if attributes match.
  * @return {Boolean}
  */
 VariationForm.prototype.isMatch = function( variation_attributes, attributes ) {
  var match = true;
  for ( var attr_name in variation_attributes ) {
   if ( variation_attributes.hasOwnProperty( attr_name ) ) {
    var val1 = variation_attributes[ attr_name ];
    var val2 = attributes[ attr_name ];
    if ( val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined && val1.length !== 0 && val2.length !== 0 && val1 !== val2 ) {
     match = false;
    }
   }
  }
  return match;
 };